# Using a Panel PC DB9 Serial Port

Tags: android, serial-port

I have a Panel PC which was Android OS. In this Panel PC, There are two DB9 Port which can use RS232, RS232/422/485.
It was possible to communicate serial data using USB port [for example FTDI chip or PL2303].
But I want to use the DB9 Port without FTDI or PL2303.
I know that linux is possible to communicate using device driver directly.
Are there any method to access to device driver directly in Android OS like Linux?

Please Help me.

Comment: Will this article be helpful?  [android-serialport-api - android_to_rs232_guideline.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-serialport-api/wikis/android_to_rs232_guideline.wiki)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I checked your link, Solution 3 was similar to what I want.
However There are DB9 RS232 Port in my Pannel pc, But In the Solution 3, Android Device have UART driver. So, I think that I cannot use it. T.T

Comment: If the DB9 serial port is originally integrated with the hardware and is supposed to be usable as a description of the system, the device driver is built in and I think that it can be used with android-serialport-api in Java. Please check the device name supported by the DB9 port (probably something starting with /dev/).